# Viewport meta tag - device width doesn't work

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport, mobile-website

I want my site witch isn't ready for mobile to open on the whole page like in the example in the right side of the image below.

Currently It's looks like the example on the left size and I can't make it work the way I want.

Whe width of the site is 1020 and I use the viewport meta tags like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1020, initial-scale=1">
```

But it doesn't work and I never see this work on mt device.

Any idea how I can make it open the way I want it to open? (Zoomed out)

[image: Zoom problem]

Comment: If your website is not mobile friendly just remove viewport meta and it should work as you want

Comment: Wow - so simple :) Thanks

Comment: check my answer for details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your website is not mobile friendly you should not enter `initial-scale` value, or remove meta viewport and you website should look as you want.

**Solution 1:**

Remove `<meta name="viewport">`. However I would not recommend this, because default viewport width on different devices is different, and your website will probably lose margins.

**Solution 2:**

Specify only `width` in `<meta name="viewport">`, like this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1020">`, this will make your website look "zoomed out" in the right way on all devices.

Comment: doesn't work with my case

Answer (score 1):

Remove viewport meta tag , if your site is not mobile friendly. It will occupy whole screen as shown in right side image